# Multiple html2canvas div content in single .pdf file

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using attached script to allocate content of div into .pdf file with jsPDF and html2canvas.
All works nicely with content of one single div (inputdiv).
However, I would like to add conent from few more additional div's into same .pdf file.
Question is how to do that?
With approach from below, only content of single div can be mapped through relevant canvas function. I tried to find some extra details in documentation and also here but unfortunately without success.
Any reference would be highly appreciated!

```
function generatePDF() {
  var doc = new jsPDF ("l", "mm", "a4", "true");
      
  html2canvas(inputdiv, { 
    width: 2000,
    height: 1450,
    scale: 2,  
    onclone: function (clonedDoc) {
    clonedDoc.getElementById('inputdiv').style.display = 'block'; 
  }
})

.then(function(canvas) {
  var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',1.0);
  const imgProps= doc.getImageProperties(imgData);
  const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
  const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
  doc.addImage(imgData, 'jpeg', 14, 19, pdfWidth, pdfHeight, undefined, 'FAST');
  doc.save('File.pdf');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how you can solve this, for 2 divs that will print on 2 pages.
Of course if you have many divs, it would need to be refactored to avoid code repetition; but this one worked for me to include 2 different divs.

```js
html2canvas(div1)
  .then((canvasDiv1) =>{
    //...
    pdf.addImage(/* ... */);
  })
  .then(() => {
    pdf.addPage();
    html2canvas(div2)
      .then((canvasDiv2) => {
        //...
        pdf.addImage(/* ... */);
        // save on the last element
        pdf.save(/* ... */);
      })
   })
```

If you need both divs to be on the same page, then just remove the pdf.addPage() and adjust the coordinates to place the second div where you need.

Comment: Thank you very much - concept works OK - i managed to solve my problem!